# System.Timers.Timer not working in If statement

Tags: asp.net, timer, webforms

I am working on Timer in my asp.net project. I want to run a function in a specific time of the day. But the timer_tick is not working in my if statement. I am testing it with msgbox  first but it is not firing.

here is my code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")

    If Label5.Text = "1:23:00" Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("Timer")
    End If
End Sub
```

I dont know how will it work. Does somebody has an idea on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `"hh:mm:ss"` to `"h:mm:ss"`. `hh` would give 01, `h` would give 1. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings. Alternatively, you can update the `if` statement to compare with `01:23:00`

Comment: You have to add a ScriptManager tag to your page to use the timer component - are you using this with ScriptManager/UpdatePanel ?